# throw new FileException('File must be readable.');

Tags: php, linux, laravel-4, centos

I'm using Laravel , The following code works on my local machine (Mac)

```
$Avatarpath =  base_path()."/uploads/image/avatar.png"
$filePath   =  base_path()."/uploads/image/myimage.png" //which gives "/var/www/myproject/uploads/image/myimage.png"

return Response::download(file_exists($filepath) ? $filepath :$Avatarpath);
```

but when I deploy the same code on linux (Centos) server , it throws the following Exception

```
throw new FileException('File must be readable.');
```

Additional info: "**uploads**" folder has drwxr-xr-x (775) permissions

Thank you your interest to fix this issue.

Comment: The folder has 775 but does the file too?

Comment: Thanks @lukasgeiter I wish you wrote it as answer then I can accept.. I just run this command to change permissions to directory content `chmod -R 775 uploads/`

Comment: Done! And you're welcome ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Important is that the permissions for the **file itself** are correct too!

Usually in this cases you should run `chmod` with the recursive flag (`-R`):

```
chmod -R 775 uploads/
```

Comment: or user:group settings.

Answer (score 0):

This Exception is thrown if function http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.isreadable.php is returning false.

Your file permissions must be denying the file read.